# Wordpress Exclude Category

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to adjust the data from a specific module and exclude posts from a specific category but i am not sure why it's not working.

```
 public function latest_tab($instance)
{
    $output = "<div class=\"jeg_tabpost_item\" id=\"jeg_tabpost_3\"><div class=\"jegwidgetpopular\">";

    $results = ModuleQuery::do_query(array(
        'category__not_in'          => array(236),
        'post_type'                 => 'post',
        'sort_by'                   => 'latest',
        'post_offset'               => 0,
        'number_post'               => $instance['limit'],
        'pagination_number_post'    => $instance['limit'],
    ));
```

For some reason posts from the category with ID 236 are still showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone needs this as well, the way that worked for me was this

```
$results = ModuleQuery::do_query(array(
    'exclude_category'          => '1,236',
    'post_type'                 => 'post',
    'sort_by'                   => 'latest',
    'post_offset'               => 0,
    'number_post'               => $instance['limit'],
    'pagination_number_post'    => $instance['limit'],
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'cat'=>'-236',
```

This specified in this comment on the codex page https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/#comment-377

Hope it works!

Comment: Thank you Jose, but i have tried that as well and it doesn't work

Comment: How about this?: 
'tax_query'=> array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => $theslugyoudontneed,
                'operator'  => 'NOT IN'
        );